# QT program containing a bash script with an if-test-then block and the escaped necessary quotes inside issues error

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shell

I am trying to run a small bash script inside a QT application which contains an if-test-then block and the necessary quotes inside the test. As the script should be compiled by QT and run by bash, the quotes have to be escaped twice, so the escaping backslashes for the quotes have to be escaped also, as I see it. Unfortunately it does not work as expected.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

QObject *parent;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
    myProcess->execute("/bin/bash -c \"x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ \\\"$x\\\" = \\\"1\\\" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi\"");
}
```

when I run the compiled program, I get the output:

```
    root@debian:~# ./proggy
    1
    /bin/bash: line 0: [: missing `]'
```

instead of the output seen here, when trying the same script in a bash terminal:

```
    root@debian:~# x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ "$x" = "1" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi
    1
    itsOne
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations of escapes and quotes in the QT-program, nothing has helped so far.

Does anybody know, what is wrong here or how to solve this riddle? Somehow it looks like the escaped quotes inside the test command break up the script seen by the bash. Why would bash not see the closing bracket if there are two necessary quotes inside the test command?

Comment: Using a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) would make this probably easier.

Comment: gcc version is 4.4.5, so raw string literals unfortunately are not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points.

Firstly **execute** is a static member of QProcess so there's no need to create an instance of QProcess.

Secondly, it's generally easier to use the [**execute** overload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute) that separates the program name from the argument list.

With that in mind what you want is probably something like...

```
QProcess::execute("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ \\\"$x\\\" = \\\"1\\\" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual bash string is wrong (the one with /bin/bash at the start, not the original). Debug this in bash first, since this won't work in bash:

```
/bin/bash -c "x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ \"$x\" = \"1\" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi"
```

You can use singles quotes to replace the outer doubles quotes so that this runs in bash:

```
/bin/bash -c 'x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ "$x" == "1" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi'
```

Then you can make your final statement:

```
myProcess->execute("/bin/bash -c 'x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ \"$x\" == \"1\" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi'");
```

Where (I can't test this last part for you since I don't have my qt pc):

```
qDebug() << "bin/bash -c 'x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ \"$x\" == \"1\" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi'" << endl;
```

should produce:

```
/bin/bash -c 'x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ "$x" == "1" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi'
```

Comment: No, the execute produces: ;: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
;: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @forenbuddy ah, ok... I'll have to debug that bit when I get on my qt pc later. But you should be able to type this `/bin/bash -c 'x=1 ; echo $x ; if [ "$x" == "1" ] ; then echo itsOne ; fi'` into a bash terminal and it works. And then your qDebug() should show the same output...